# How to safely handle raw (file) data in Java?

Tags: http, scala, request, playframework-2.0

An image gets corrupted while being retrieved (through HTTP) and then sent (through HTTP) to a database. Image's raw data is handled in String form.

The service sends a GET for an image file, receives response with the raw image data (response's body) and the Content-Type. Then, a PUT request is sent with the aforementioned request's body and Content-Type header. (The PUT request is constructed by providing the body in String) This PUT request is sent to a RESTful database (CouchDB), creating an [attachment](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/documents.html#put-db-doc-attachment) (for those unfamiliar with CouchDB an attachment acts like a static file).

Now I have the original image, which my service GETs and PUTs to a database, and this 'copy' of the original image, that I can now GET from the database. If I then `curl --head -v "[copy's url]" it has the Content-Type of the original image, but Content-Length has changed, went from 200kb to about 400kb. If I GET the 'copy' image with a browser, it is not rendered, whereas, the original renders fine. It is corrupted.

What might be the cause? My guess is that while handling the raw data as a string, my framework guesses the encoding wrong and corrupts it. I have not been able to confirm or deny this. How could I handle this raw data/request body in a safe manner, or how could I properly handle the encoding (if that proves to be the problem)?

Details: [Play2 Framework's HTTP client](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WS%24), Scala. Below a test to reproduce:

```scala
"able to copy an image" in {
  def waitFor[T](future:Future[T]):T = { // to bypass futures
    Await.result(future, Duration(10000, "millis"))
  }
  val originalImageUrl = "http://laughingsquid.com/wp-content/uploads/grumpy-cat.jpg"
  val couchdbUrl = "http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/testdb"
  val getOriginal:ws.Response = waitFor(WS.url(originalImageUrl).get)
  getOriginal.status mustEqual 200
  val rawImage:String = getOriginal.body
  val originalContentType = getOriginal.header("Content-Type").get

  // need an empty doc to have something to attach the attachment to
  val emptyDocUrl = couchdbUrl + "/empty_doc"
  val putEmptyDoc:ws.Response = waitFor(WS.url(emptyDocUrl).put("{}"))
  putEmptyDoc.status mustEqual 201
  //uploading an attachment will require the doc's revision
  val emptyDocRev = (putEmptyDoc.json \ "rev").as[String]

  // create actual attachment/static file
  val attachmentUrl = emptyDocUrl + "/0"
  val putAttachment:ws.Response = waitFor(WS.url(attachmentUrl)
    .withHeaders(("If-Match", emptyDocRev), ("Content-Type", originalContentType))
    .put(rawImage))
  putAttachment.status mustEqual 201

  // retrieve attachment
  val getAttachment:ws.Response = waitFor(WS.url(attachmentUrl).get)
  getAttachment.status mustEqual 200
  val attachmentContentType = getAttachment.header("Content-Type").get

  originalContentType mustEqual attachmentContentType
  val originalAndCopyMatch = getOriginal.body == getAttachment.body
  originalAndCopyMatch aka "original matches copy" must beTrue // << false
}
```

Fails at the last 'must':

```
[error] x  able to copy an image
[error]    original matches copy is false (ApplicationSpec.scala:112)
```

Comment: The format for retrieval and handling of this data is `Array[Byte]`. Other kinds of sequence (of `Byte`) work as well, but are not as efficient. I'll refrain from answering because I don't know the HTTP client you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion to `String` is definitely going to cause problems. You need to work with the bytes as Daniel mentioned.

Looking at the source it looks like `ws.Response` is just a wrapper. If you get to the underlying class then there are some methods that may help you. On the Java side, someone made a commit on GitHub to expose more ways of getting the response data other than a `String`.

I'm not familiar with scala but something like this may work:

```
getOriginal.getAHCResponse.getResponseBodyAsBytes

// instead of getOriginal.body
```

---

**WS.scala**
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala

**WS.java**
Here you can see that `Response` has some new methods, `getBodyAsStream()` and `asByteArray`.
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/libs/WS.java

Comment: The answer to my problem was handling raw data as array of bytes exclusively. It's also bizarre that the `asByteArray` method didn't get into the scala version yet.